# How to sum float values from the following json response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest

*(disclaimer: I’m brand new to python and this is my first question on stackoverflow, please bear with me!)*

**Context:**

I’m trying to automate some daily tasks and chose to learn python for that purpose,

one of the tasks is connecting to an api and pulling the hourly revenues for date “x”

my current ‘program’ successfully connects and retrieves data for Input() date

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

autodatemonth = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() + timedelta(1), '%Y-%m')

enterday = input('Enter day: \n') 
AutoStartDate = str(autodatemonth) + '-' + str(enterday)
MonthPlusOne = int(enterday) + 1
AutoEndDate = str(autodatemonth) + '-' + str(MonthPlusOne) 

    parameters = {'start_date': AutoStartDate, 'end_date': AutoEndDate, 'fields': ['date', 'revenue'], 'start_at_row': 1, 'api_key': ‘xxx’, 'id': xxx, 'row_limit':24}

    # Make a get request with the parameters.
    response = requests.get("https://example.com/api/Reports/HourlySummary", params=parameters)

lst = response.json()

import pprint
pprint.pprint(lst)

# getting closer
for info in lst['data']:
    print(info['revenue'])
```

the above code spits out a response like this:

```
{'data': [{'date': '2018-05-15T02:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T03:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T04:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T05:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T06:00:00', 'revenue': 20.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T07:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T08:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T09:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T10:00:00', 'revenue': 38.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T11:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T12:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T13:00:00', 'revenue': 93.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T14:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T15:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T16:00:00', 'revenue': 75.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T17:00:00', 'revenue': 27.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T18:00:00', 'revenue': 91.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T19:00:00', 'revenue': 75.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T20:00:00', 'revenue': 75.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T21:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T22:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T23:00:00', 'revenue': 38.0}],
 'message': None,
 'row_count': 24,
 'success': True}
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
20.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
38.0
0.0
0.0
93.0
0.0
0.0
75.0
27.0
91.0
75.0
75.0
0.0
0.0
38.0
```

I got stuck trying to figure out how to add the revenue float values from the above response.

Looked into multiple questions and answers but still trying to put things together for my own case.

Could you point me in the right direction?

Edit:
I simply want the total sum of revenues

Comment: so you want the sum of revenues ?

Comment: yes, exactly. Gonna edit the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(sum(info['revenue'] for info in lst['data']))
```

using https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum

and a generator expression https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Answer (score 0):

Using a list comprehension with `sum()`.

**Ex:**

```
lst = {'data': [{'date': '2018-05-15T02:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T03:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T04:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T05:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T06:00:00', 'revenue': 20.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T07:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T08:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T09:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T10:00:00', 'revenue': 38.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T11:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T12:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T13:00:00', 'revenue': 93.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T14:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T15:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T16:00:00', 'revenue': 75.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T17:00:00', 'revenue': 27.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T18:00:00', 'revenue': 91.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T19:00:00', 'revenue': 75.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T20:00:00', 'revenue': 75.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T21:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T22:00:00', 'revenue': 0.0},
          {'date': '2018-05-15T23:00:00', 'revenue': 38.0}],
 'message': None,
 'row_count': 24,
 'success': True}

res = sum([i['revenue'] for i in lst["data"]])
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
532.0
```

Comment: this gives me an error:

    res = sum([i['revenue'] for i in data["data"]])
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: You should be using `lst ` instead of data `res = sum([i['revenue'] for i in lst["data"]])
`